# Regex for accepting alphanumeric and with special characters but not special characters alone

Tags: regex

So i need to apply some regex that checks if the text entered is alphanumeric with possible special characters, such as apostrophes, but should not accept special characters without alphanumeric characters.

For example:

- "Someone's thing" returns 5 results
- "(')" returns "invalid"

I've currently got:

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");

            if (!regexItem.IsMatch(searchTerm))
            {
                return null;
            }
```

That works for alphanumeric values and blocks inputs with just special characters but if there is an apostrophe in the search term, it will return null.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

new code looks like this.

```
var regexItem = new Regex("^(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9 '()]* $");

            if (!regexItem.IsMatch(searchTerm))
            {
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: Can you write a more detalied example?

Comment: Try using a positive lookahead `^(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Za-z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9 '"()]*$`  https://regex101.com/r/rGaTEl/1

Comment: Not sure quite how to make it more detailed. Perhaps I haven't worded it quite right. A little bit of context, if i do a search for ' it returns thousands of results which takes an unacceptable time to come back. Therefore I don't want to let users search for any special characters alone. Hope that makes things clearer?

Comment: the positive look ahead seems to be right on that link you provided but when i put it into my code, it's now returning null for all inputs?

Comment: @rubidge96 It seems to work in this demo https://ideone.com/SgXd71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use 
[as-is]
`var regexItem = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$");`
[to-be]
`var regexItem = new Regex("^([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(')?[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)*$");`

Comment: That will allow the char/string ' or '''.

Comment: @seunggabi that is perfect. Thank you very much! :)